# Trying to get ImageJ to analyze my image and report back a list of L*a*b* values for each pixel . Can't see how to do in ImageJ

Tags: imagej

I want software to take my image and analyze it and report back a list of L*a*b* color values for each pixel.  I suppose any color space could work, it's just that CIELab is the one I'm familiar with.  Really what I want to do is very simple:  for a given image, if I have the L*a*b* per pixel I should be able to calculate a median value and a standard deviation for the whole image.  I am simply trying to take a given image and quantify the level of color non-uniformity in it, compared to a median value for the whole image.  Thought experiment, for example.  If I took a picture of a pile of grains of salt and pepper side by side in the same image,  I would expect the color non-uniformity (i.e standard deviation) to quite high, compared to an image where I have taken that exact same pile of salt and pepper and evenly mixed them (which would have much lower color non-uniformity/std dev).

I have tried looking around in every menu heading and sub-item in ImageJ and really not finding what I'm looking for.  I'm a total newb to ImageJ, and not a programmer either.  But perfectly cable to find and use a library or macro / plugin if something exists,  and place it in the right folder structure :-) (if there is a solution already out there that needs to be downloaded and put in the right place.)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you really want and what you didn't find by searching the menus. Fact is that you can convert your image to RGB, HSB, and Lab colour space under the menu "Image >> Type" but there are also plugins that convert to other colour spaces such as CMYK. Measuring Median and StdDev in every colour channel is performed by "Set Measurements..." and then "Measure" under the menu "Analyze". Please make sure you've thoroughly studied the [ImageJ User Guide](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/index.html).

Comment: Thank you Herbie for the comment.  I was missing the function that "Set Measurements" provides.  Now that I understand that it is there and what it does,  it seems that what I was trying to do is quite simple.   thanks again!